# How can I animate text moving in blender 2D?

Tags: text-object

I want to animate a sign lowering from the top of the frame, swinging around, then dropping. The only problem I'm having is animating the text I have on it to move with the sign. I don't have the brain capacity to try to convert the text to grease pencil without screwing up the entire thing. So, does anyone know of a way I can just animate the text as text?

Comment: did you try to parent your text to your sign?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually resorted to using an external image editor at times, such as an animated Happy Birthday sign/banner/cloth-flag. I use Photoshop or the free Gimp photo editor, create a background image or solid color, and then use the Gimp text feature to add text and export it as PNG or JPG file. I then use the blender File -> Import -> "Images as Planes" so that I now have my sign that I can animate.

This allows for more exotic simulations of what you're looking for, with the [image] example of the plane having a cloth simulation.

[image]

Gimp file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6o949w34uilu1l/name%20banner.xcf?dl=0) as there's no way to pack it into a blend file.

Comment: otherwise the suggestion offered by @Chris would work, and allows you to also animate Text parameters as well.